# JavaScript makes browser load forever and crash Safari

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a little script that'll inject a `<script>` tag in a page.

Here it is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var url = 'http://my_url.com/js/widget_rss.js?cle=4c65683101e22&host=' + window.location.hostname;
    var scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
    scriptTag.src = url;
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    (head || document.body).appendChild(scriptTag);
</script>
```

It is working, it calls the other file and the file runs but it makes the browser load forever...

Any ideas what's wrong about it?

Thanks!

Comment: Btw, you can use lazy load for this http://github.com/rgrove/lazyload

Comment: There could be something wrong with the script you're trying to load. Can you post its code?

Answer (score 1):

Every time I need this kind of script loading I use this snippet:

```
function loadScript(scriptName) {
    var customScript = document.createElement('script');
            customScript.type = 'text/javascript';
            customScript.async = true;
  customScript.src = scriptName;
    (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(customScript);
};//loadScript
```

After this, you just call with `loadScript('path/to/script')`.

If you need more advanced stuff (like callback and CSS loaders) you can use [lazyload](http://github.com/rgrove/lazyload).

Comment: I do almost the same thing as your snippet. But I still tried it and it does exactly the same thing... :/ thanks tho

Comment: Then the problem may be the script you trying to load :)